# Magento 2 disabling product by custom attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products

Is there a way in disabling a product by checking its custom attribute?

example scenario:
'date_expiration' 
if date_expiration < today the product status will be disabled.

I have tried creating a custom front_end template for Magento_Catalog, that checks attribute date_expiration when expiration met it will redirect to homepage. I know this is not good solution because it will appear on catalog list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a event for this in your module config.xml :

```
    <frontend>
    <event>
        <catalog_product_is_salable_after>
            <observer>
                <any_name>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>yourMethodName</method>
                </any_name>
            </observer>
        </catalog_product_is_salable_after>
    </event>
</frontend>
```

and in module observer file you have to write your method

```
    public function yourMethodName($observer)
    {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $salable = $observer->getSalable(); 
    $date_expiration = $product->getDateExpiration()
    if( your logic for stop showing product)
    {
        $salable->setIsSalable(false);
    }
    return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to override product listing block and filter the collection with your custom attribute value.